# Can I customise the UIAlertView [iPhone iOs 4]?

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I try to run this a sample that customise UIAlertView but it doesn't work.

http://joris.kluivers.nl/iphone-dev/?p=CustomAlert

I would like to change the background image of the UIAlertView.

Can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can do it. I'm not sure what other type of answer you're looking for. If you're looking for help getting the example to work, you're probably better off contacting the developer of that example.

Comment: Sample from link worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have customized UIAlertView before, which broke when a new OS was released (4.2, specifically). I recommend implementing your own custom view instead of trying to customizing UIAlertView.

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes, you can, but it's frowned upon. Modifying the private view hierarchy of a framework-provided control is dangerous and can cause incompatibility with future versions of the OS. What's more, you're breaking UI conventions if you start changing these things, and that should not be done lightly.

Answer (score 1):

I have a UIAlertView replacement, shared on on github, that supports using a custom background:

https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView