# Customisation of UIAlertview not showing in iphone?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have an  application in iphone where i am customizing my alertview using the bellow code. It is working fine in the simulator.But when i added it to my iphone it is showing the same blue one.Not my customised view.Can anybody help me please?

```
UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"canceled"
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
//[alert setUIColor:[UIColor brownColor]]; 
/*[alert show];
[alert release];*/

//UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"canceled"
                                                       //delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[theAlert show];

UILabel *theTitle = [theAlert valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
[theTitle setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

UILabel *theBody = [theAlert valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
[theBody setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
theBody.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pop_up.png"];    
theImage = [theImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:28 topCapHeight:28];
CGSize theSize = [theAlert frame].size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theSize);    
[theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theSize.width, theSize.height)];    
theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//[[theAlert layer] setContents:[theImage CGImage]];
[[theAlert layer] setContents:(id)[theImage CGImage]];
[theAlert release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an old conversation for the same topic that can help you.
[Can I customise the UIAlertView [iPhone iOs 4]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798271/can-i-customise-the-uialertview-iphone-ios-4)

I recommend you not to customize it, because in futures release you may have compatibility problems.
If you strongly need to use another AlertView create a new one, if not why not to use the native one that works great. In case, it doesn't works correctly don't worry sure that they will in next release.